# Ajax parameters are encrypted when passed to Java contoller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have below object named itemInfo in Javascript-

```
   itemInfo = {

catalogId:[{"catId":"RS-122-2001","quantity":"1"},{"catId:"RS-122-2002","quantity":"1"}]

}
```

I am passing this object through ajax to a java controller-

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/bin/path/servlet',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                productId: itemInfo.catalogId,
                operation: "addToCart"
            },
            success: function(obj) {
                if (obj) {
                    //do something
                }
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }

        });
```

When I see the request, its sent like this-

```
<<hostName>>/bin/path/servlet?productId%5B0%5D%5BcatId%5D=RS-122-2001&productId%5B0%5D%5Bquantity%5D=1&productId%5B1%5D%5BcatId%5D=RS-122-2002&productId%5B1%5D%5Bquantity%5D=1&operation=addToCart
```

Decoded URL parameters looks like this-

```
productId[0][catId]=RS-122-2001&productId[0][quantity]=1&productId[1][catId]=RS-122-2002&productId[1][quantity]=1&operation=addToCart
```

Its not making any sense in Java and passed values are not readable. Is something wrong with implementation? How can I retrieve passed values in Java controller?

Comment: it is just url encode.

Comment: Yes that I understand. But why is it encoded? and how do I access fields in java?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to stringify your data:

```
productId: JSON.stringify(itemInfo.catalogId)
```

By the way i don't think is a good idea to post complex object by "GET" method.
I suggest to change your servlet to accept method "POST" then modify your script type to "POST".

Comment: Instead of directly accessing parameters, first I had to convert complete value in to JSON object. Then access values by iterating JSON object.